# What does "\.self" actually do in Swift/SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I don't fully understand what exactly `\.self` does in the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var numbers = [Int]()
    @State private var currentNumber = 1

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) {
                    Text("\($0)")
                }
            }

            Button("Add Number") {
                self.numbers.append(self.currentNumber)
                self.currentNumber += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm following this: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/deleting-items-using-ondelete.

I have a really basic understanding of the language right now, so I may not understand high level explanations, so would prefer very simple explanations or analogies with verbose descriptions. I think it is setting the `id`for each `list` item as each item in the numbers array? Correct me if wrong - but is each `id` being set as whatever `Int` is in each entry of the numbers array? If so, then what does `\` actually do when typing `\.self` and what does `.self` actually do in combination with `\`?

Comment: From the same site: [Why does \.self work for ForEach?](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/why-does-self-work-for-foreach)

Comment: Read about keypaths. `Int(1)` with applied key path `\.self` gives `Int(1)`, ie `\.self` means self, literally.

Comment: Thank you @Asperi and @pawello2222, I went and read [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/why-does-self-work-for-foreach) and [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-are-keypaths); from what I understand, \ begins a keypath that references an object like an array or struct? as long as `\.self` conforms to hashable (which apparently arrays do), then swift will automatically create a hash of the `Int(1)` to use as the id? And swift just implicitly knows to do this when you use `ForEach(_ , id: hashable)` ??

Comment: Question: How does the id: field know that '.self' should refer to the current item in the ForEach and not class that contains the function that is calling the ForEach? (since self usually refers to the class you're in.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

. key paths. ForEach needs every object unique. give them unique ids with id:.self. if your objects are identifiable you dont need .self.
[i wrote about this in medim if you want you can check out](https://medium.com/dev-genius/what-is-self-in-foreach-key-paths-in-swiftui-8418dbdac505)

Answer (score 1):

`id: \.self` tells Swift to use as unique id (keypath) the hash of the object.

It explains why the name  "self" is used.

`id: \.self` is especially useful for the basic Swift types like `Integer` and `String`.

On the one the hand  the developer cannot add to them an unique id.

On the other hand all they are *hashable* so we can use `id: \.self`.

`id: \.self` is useful not only for `ForEach`, but for `List` also.